# Is there a "statute of limitations" on misbehavior?

Tags: support, moderation, behavior, policy, ban

Background: A "statute of limitations" is a [law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_limitations) that provides that certain very old transgressions are no longer punishable today - the idea that e.g. it's a waste of everyone's time to search through security camera footage from the 1990's to cite people for littering *today*.

A user on Meta Stack Overflow recently [posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397481/6471538) a question in which he expressed concern that he had been review-banned for a bad review that had happened several weeks in the past. He speculated on whether there is or ought to be a "statute of limitations" on whether uncaught mistakes that are discovered later should be treated the same as recent mistakes.

**Is there a concept of a "statute of limitations" in Stack Exchange moderation**, whether for robo-reviewing, spamming, violating the Code of Conduct, or otherwise? More specifically, how are moderators taught to compare the discovery of old, uncaught misbehavior with users who are caught right away?

For example, suppose a moderator catches an established, middle-reputation user posting hate speech today, and during the investigation, finds out that another established, middle-reputation user posted hate speech in 2015, was never caught, but has since displayed acceptable behavior. Would we expect the dispositions to be different (e.g. suspend the first account but not the second), or is "hate speech is hate speech, no matter when it happened" the rule?

Another way of phrasing the question is whether a user who did something bad and corrected their behavior *without* first being caught by a moderator has a [sword of Damocles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damocles) continually hanging over them (i.e. that regardless of their good behavior today, they are likely to face negative account action as soon as the prior misconduct is discovered) or whether a time will come that the prior misbehavior, even though never punished, is no longer relevant.

To be clear, I don't expect there to be a *specific* time limit (e.g. an exact number of hours, days, or weeks), but am more interested in to what extent "time between misconduct and getting caught" is considered relevant when moderators decide what action to take. E.g. I'm not expecting to hear "Oh yes, the statute of limitations is one year. Yesterday we caught one of our most wanted trolls of Spring 2022 at the 368-day mark and we were forbidden by policy from taking action....", but rather something like "Yes, time passed and recent good behavior matters. Yesterday I discovered that one of our 100k+ rep users posted a self-promoting answer without adequate disclosure in May 2011 and deleted it a few weeks later. I decided not to shred his account as a spammer because of his recent non-problematic behavior...." or "No, time passed under the bridge is irrelevant. Yesterday I discovered that one of our top users was part of a vote fraud circle from late 2011 to mid-2012 after which all indications are that he only voted appropriately. I suspended his sorry behind until 2024 for vote fraud! No matter how many years or decades have passed, we will find you and we will ban you!".

Comment: While I think this is an interesting question, the description of the linked example is … less accurate than I'd prefer to see. In the linked example, the action for which the user was review banned was < 3 weeks in the past, which I wouldn't characterize as "several weeks in the past". Personally, I would have said "a couple weeks in the past", or "a couple/few weeks …", but describing it as "several" is … a stretch. OTOH, I think that it's quite reasonable for this question to be asking about things that are "several weeks in the past", just that the linked example doesn't fit that.

Answer (score 11):

I am not aware of the general policy or consensus, but I will share my thoughts.
Since such situations are generally rare, they are worth considering on a **case-by-case basis**:

- General suspensions should be used cautiously for the wrong-doings that were done a long time ago. In many cases, a simple custom mod message is enough.
- I would resort to an actual suspension only in a small number of cases, particularly, when that user displayed and continues to display certain undesirable.

**General points** that should apply in my opinion no matter what:

- If the *infraction* would have warranted a certain mod message in the past, it certainly deserves it even 10 years from the time of the wrong-doing. A mod message is just a message and simply informs the user about the concern.
- Spam/hate speech/other bad content should be deleted. If that triggers an automatic (!) flag, so be it.
- Review bans are still ok. They are not necessarily a punishment, and are, in part, designed to inform the user about an incorrect review process. In general, the moderator should be ready to lift the review ban/reduce the duration provided the user understands what had been done wrong.
- Continuous review banning for similar past infractions is useless if the user had already improved their review quality.

**Time limit**:

I agree with the assessment that defining a particular time limit is hard. I also consider that having an exact time limit is counterproductive, and I would say that it should be left at the moderators' discretion. Paradoxically, in some sense, I am advocating for the necessity of [*statutory interpretation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statutory_interpretation) by not introducing an explicit statute at all. But *several weeks* certainly does not sound like *past* to me.

Comment: Also, if you’re afraid of getting caught for a past bad post/comment you made you have one excellent option available: go handle it yourself by deleting/editing it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

We're not a legal system.

Our fundamental goal is to improve behaviour, set clear guidelines for problematic behavior, and guide a user towards a better way.

> A user on Meta Stack Overflow recently posted a question in which he expressed concern that he had been review-banned for a bad review that had happened several weeks in the past.

Review bans *should* be automatic. I'm under the impression the automatic process is a little broken, and the moderation team has been picking up the slack. Its a situation that well, is unusual.

If problematic behaviour of any sort is not caught quickly and addressed, I'd consider it a failure. We're neither omniscient nor do we always get informed of issues so, stuff *does* occationally slip through the cracks.

I'd certainly want to avoid a situation akin to [James Gunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gunn#Firing_from_Disney_and_reinstatement), where some old mistake is dug up years after the fact. Paradoxically, if we find that there's a pattern of something we don't want, over a pattern of years, and we've failed to spot it, that may need rectification.

> For example, suppose a moderator catches an established, middle-reputation user posting hate speech today, and during the investigation, finds out that another established, middle-reputation user posted hate speech in 2015, was never caught, but has since displayed acceptable behavior

Which leads us to "what's an appropriate way to deal with this?" It would certainly be worth an investigation - is this a pattern or a one off. An annotation might be in order for the other user. Both posts should be deleted. We might mod message or informally inform the user if it seems necessary.

Then comes the real question - how was this missed over half a decade?

> Another way of phrasing the question is whether a user who did something bad and corrected their behavior without first being caught by a moderator has a sword of Damocles continually hanging over them (i.e. that regardless of their good behavior today, they are likely to face negative account action as soon as the prior misconduct is discovered) or whether a time will come that the prior misbehavior, even though never punished, is no longer relevant.

Punishment isn't the goal. There is no sword of Damocles - in situations like this, *personally* my concern is for the impact on the community and whether it would happen again over getting an appropriate punishment. Once again, in these situations *swift*, fair actions matter.

I don't suspend someone for hate speech or harassment or whatever other nonsense just to punish them - its to protect other users primarily. A suspension over a one off instance may make no sense after years of a user being in good standing. Someone having a pattern of low level poor behaviour going under the radar over a period of a few months might warrant action to discourage it if we missed it for a while.

In short, we determine the approprate actions based on the broader situation and try our best to pick the fairest, most effective option to resolve the situations.